How can I type korean in Ubuntu 24.04
I upgraded my version to 24.04 from 22.04, and there is no preference for the language input source.
When I used 22.04, I added my toggle key to type Korean in preference. But in Ubuntu 24.04 only the keyboard layout remains. So I don't know how to add a toggle key in this version. Also I can't find which key is the default toggle key.
I've tried suggestion in the link below, but that only changes the language and not typing in that language.
Switching language by Alt + Shift after update from Ubuntu 22.04 beta to release is not working
I'm using LG Gram.
Please help me

Does this answer your question? How to add korean keyboard?

I solve it!
https://mech2cs.tistory.com/entry/Ubuntu-2004-%ED%95%9C%EA%B8%80%EC%9E%85%EB%A0%A5%EA%B8%B0-%EC%84%A4%EC%B9%98
This link helped me.

@MemoryWavve Please write down your solution as an answer in the box below

Actually, the suggested solution (installing fcitx-hangul) totally crashed my system.
But what worked for me was installing Korean through Language support app (method system IBus).
